# Null column equality

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table called `pat_info`. In this table I have column `id_number` which is nullable. When I write this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM pat_info
WHERE id_number = id_number
    AND first_name = 'adam'
```

It does not retrieve any thing cause 'adam' row does not contain value in `id_number`

So I need to retrieve 'adam' row without delete.

`Id_number = id_number` cause it is required.

Comment: Why do you need `WHERE id_number = id_number` ?

Comment: What do you mean by "is required"? By whom? Or by what? That is a very unusual requirement indeed; it is very unlikely that we can help you unless you explain more about that "requirement".

Comment: Also - what is a "prob"? I am not familiar with the term.

Comment: So the whole "prob" comes down to the part of the WHERE clause which specifies `id_number = id_number`. If the column was 100% populated the clause wouldn't do anything. So you need to explain why you think that filter is required. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Cause i will take this query in oracle forms and put the whole where condition in block where clause property with .modification in where condition to be where id_number = nvl(:id ,id_number) so if user put value in id_number it will retrieve adam with id_number  otherwise it will retrieve anyone called adam and doesnt have id_number

Comment: And the problem if i put someone else say 'joe' who doesn't have id_number , this row doesn't retrieved

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that actually describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. If you remove the unnecessarily repeated tag information *Oracle SQL*, it leaves *code prob*, which isn't useful at all. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to be of use to a future reader here who is scanning through a list of search results, and *code prob* won't be of much use to them.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need that `WHERE` clause in the first place, most likely.  Just use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM pat_info
WHERE first_name = 'adam';
```

The reason your current query might be failing is that if `id_number` happens to be `NULL`, then the check `id_number = id_number` would fail, because `NULL` (semantically meaning "not known") does not equal itself.

If you must include that dummy check in the `WHERE` clause, then try using `WHERE 1 = 1`, i.e. this:

```
SELECT *
FROM pat_info
WHERE first_name = 'adam' AND 1 = 1;
```

Comment: But i need to put id_numer =id_number

Comment: @MahmoudElkashab I don't see why...if you must, then use `WHERE 1 = 1`, or maybe use a primary key column which can never be null.

Comment: If i use primary key i will have to put primary key in all columns

Comment: The primary key _is_ a column, and every table should arguably have one.  I don't understand your problem.

Comment: I already have a primary key in column called pat_code but i did not need a primary key in this column cause this column is optional

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, if ID_NUMBER is NULL in the row you're trying to retrieve, you will not be able to retrieve that row if you specify `ID_NUMBER = ID_NUMBER` in your query. The reason for this is that in a relational database, NULL will not compare as "equal" to any value, including NULL. So if ID_NUMBER is NULL, the test `ID_NUMBER = ID_NUMBER` is the same as `NULL = NULL`, and this will never return TRUE. Any comparison where NULL is present on either side of the comparison will return NULL. That's just how it works.

## EDIT

One possible workaround would be to rewrite the query as:

```
Select *
  from pat_info
  Where (id_number = id_number OR 
         ID_NUMBER IS NULL) and
        first_name = 'adam'
```

In this way the requirement to use `ID_NUMBER = ID_NUMBER` in the query is satisfied, at least in my view.

Thanks, @TimBiegeleisen. :-)

Comment: Just like the OP's query, the query in your solution will fail. The OP may have meant `first_name` rather than `first name`. I don't think copy-and-paste helps anyone, if we copy and paste nonsense.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use LIKE,

```
SELECT *
  FROM pat_info
 WHERE '%'||id_number||'%' LIKE '%'||id_number||'%'
   AND first_name = 'adam'
```

Although, I don't get the sense why you put this condition,

```
id_number = id_number
```